# Piece back together numpy slices into original array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

if you split a numpy array using slices like this:

Assuming data looked like this:
    [[ Y X X X....]
    [Y X X X....]]

```
X_test = data_test[:, 1:]
y_test = data_test[:, 0]
```

I assumed this would work but I cannot find documentation in the process.

```
test_assembled = [:, y_test:X_test]
```

Answer (score 2):

With

```
X_test = data_test[:, 1:]
y_test = data_test[:, 0]
```

changes to `X_test` or `y_test` will be seen in `data_test`.  So you don't need to reassemble them to propagate changes.  They are `views`.

An assembly using `np.concatante` (or its derivatives, `stack`, `c_` etc) will produce a new array, with its own databuffer.  That may, or may not be what you want.

In this case the only tricky part about concatenating them is the `X_test` is 2d, while `y_test` (indexed with a scalar) is 1d.  The concatenating has to take that into account.  The explicit way is to

```
y_temp = y_test[:,None]
new_data = np.concatenate((y_temp, X_test), axis=1)
```

`np.column_stack` and `c_` are convenience functions that can do that `y_temp` step for you.

Equally good is to construct a 'blank' receiver array, and copy the arrays with the same slicing notation.

```
new_data = np.zeros_like(data_test)
new_data[:, 1:] = X_test
new_data[:,0] = y_test
```

In fact you could do that assignment to `data_test`, but there's no need to do that.

---

Verification:

```
In [135]: data_test = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [136]: data_test
Out[136]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [137]: X_test = data_test[:,1:]
In [139]: y_test = data_test[:,0]
In [140]: y_test
Out[140]: array([0, 4, 8])
In [141]: y_test *= 10
In [142]: data_test
Out[142]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [40,  5,  6,  7],
       [80,  9, 10, 11]])
In [143]: np.concatenate((y_test[:,None], X_test), axis=1)
Out[143]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [40,  5,  6,  7],
       [80,  9, 10, 11]])
In [144]: np.column_stack((y_test, X_test))
Out[144]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [40,  5,  6,  7],
       [80,  9, 10, 11]])
In [145]: new = np.zeros_like(data_test)
In [146]: new[:,1:] = X_test
In [147]: new[:,0] = y_test/10
In [148]: new
Out[148]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use `np.c_`:

```
a = np.identity(4)
x, y = a[:,0], a[:,1:]
np.c_[x,y]
# array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

`np.c_` conveniently handles the "missing dimension" in `a[:,0]` for you.